# How to query `can_unique` by index name?

Tags: postgresql

I found [this documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-INDEXAM-PROPS)

[image]

I suppose I may use that to check if index with `name` supports unique or not.

How to write this query?

Comment: That's a property of an access method, not of an index that has a name. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Maybe these help: https://github.com/darold/pgFormatter/blob/master/t/pg-test-files/expected/amutils.sql https://medium.com/postgres-professional/indexes-in-postgresql-2-ad687857989

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out if an index is unique or not, run

```
SELECT indisunique
FROM pg_index
WHERE indexrelid = 'indexname'::regclass;
```

To find out if the index access method of an index supports unique indexes in general, run

```
SELECT pg_indexam_has_property(relam, 'can_unique')
FROM pg_class
WHERE relkind = 'i' AND relname = 'indexname';
```